# Adding a large number with a small number in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, addition, largenumber

I wrote a program in python which the program has one number with high value (T) and another number with a low value (a). When I add them up, the small number is ignored due to its low value. How can I fix this problem. The part of my program which makes this problem is below.

```
import random
lambd = 110
T = 56562719533.0
a = random.expovariate(lambd)
T2 = T + a
print T
print T2
```

Comment: How do you know it's being ignored?

Comment: I don't think it's ignored. It just doesn't show up in a `print`.

Comment: @khelwood That was sort of the point I was hoping would come up. Interestingly, with python3, the numbers *are* printed differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did add the small number but didn't print enough significant figures to see it.

```
import random
lambd = 110
T = 56562719533.0
a = random.expovariate(lambd)
T2 = T + a
print a
print T
print '%.10f' % T2
# prints: 0.00436707252696
# prints: 56562719533.0
# prints: 56562719533.0043640137
```

The `'%.10f'` tells Python to print 10 digits after the decimal point.